# Limitation of streaming data ingest into Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to perform an update query on a table that queries and joins data from another table before writing to the update table. Unfortunately, when I try and apply the update policy to the table, I receive the following error;

[image: ADX Updaet Policy Error]

The Microsoft docs describe the limitation the update policies on tables that have a streaming ingest policy configured on them are only able to reference the ingested data in their update queries.

To try and navigate that I have a staging table in between the streamed table and the transformation table, which I thought may have helped, by not directly referencing the streamed data in the complex update policy. So my current data flow is as follows:

- T1 - Messages streamed from Event Hub
- T2 - Simple update policy to parse data from the raw message in T1 to columns
- T3 - Parsed partial data from T1 using a simple update policy
- T4 - combined data from T2 and T3 that are merged to produce a row in the table, this is the table that is having the issue with the update policy being applied.

There is no direct link between T4 and T1 which is why it is strange that I am seeing this error unless the limitation means that as soon as you introduce any streaming ingest policies to any table in the database, you are limited with the update policies that can be applied.

I have confirmed that my update policies all work when using the default 'batch ingest' method.

I have also confirmed that the streaming ingest policy is only applied to T1 and not database-wide.

Has anyone has any experience of anyting similar when trying to apply update policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation described in docs is relevant for the data arriving in streaming ingestion itself and is not scoped to single level of update policy.